# What changes occur in linux graphics stack when a GPU driver is installed?

Tags: kernel, drivers, graphics, mesa

This image from Wikipedia illustrates the so-called "linux graphics stack".

[image: linux graphics stack]

Suppose I buy a laptop that is so new that there exists no dedicated device driver for its GPU. Hence, the graphic quality is bad until one day some decent developer creates an excellent free driver and by updating my linux distro I notice that the graphic quality has become superb and flawless. My question is: how has the update changed the graphics stack? In particular, I'd like to know if the new graphics driver is merely run in user-space or at least some part of it is run in kernel-space. By the way, I'm not a very advanced linux user. Please keep that in mind. :)

Comment: "Graphic quality is bad". No. It may just be slow (so it may depends on what do you use a GPU). You have in any case *basic* support for figures, and with modern CPU, it will be fast. Not to play smoothly videogames. -- Then it is maybe no so important to know if drivers are userspace or not: in any case you need them. (and in reality you may get drivers on both sides)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, can't speed be considered as part of quality? Like a low-speed car.

Answer (score 1):

The image stack doesn't really change, on such figures (so on abstract level). Most programs do not notice any difference (but e.g. if they measure the frames per second).

But there are few changes on the files which are read.

The first change is in Linux Kernel, or better kernel modules. A new video card may need a new driver. Note: many drivers are pretty generic, so if you just use a new GPU from an established family, most things will work, possibly not using the full potential. Or eventually one should put some boot parameters (or better: module parameters) to accept an unknown card. Kernel mostly handle permissions and resource, so not the *core* use of a video card.

The other changes are in user space, e.g. in the above figure: libGL (rendering, calculation), and there may be other drivers to handle other parts (colour management, screen management, computation in GPU, etc.). When you install a program, the package manager will install a generic driver, which will do the work possibly using the GPU (or just telling that there is no GPU available). Here the main work is done (or better: delegated): a program tell: I need such effect, and the library will do it on CPU, delegate to GPU or a a mix (decompose and send a lot of actions to GPU). Again: if you do not use a new family of GPU, some feature will be recognized and used. Not at full potential, but it will offload the CPU.

Do not over-valuate the differences on GPUs. Most architecture remains the same. There will be a lot of improvements on benchmarks but the architecture is the same: There may be some optimization, new cores, more memory, etc. which may be recognized by older drivers. There may be also new features (e.g. ray tracing, 3D shadows, etc.), but in such case, a new driver will not help much, until there will be programs that uses such features (and libraries/drivers that implement it).

So on Ubuntu (and other distributions): you may get some support (very basic, aka VESA on new types, advanced but not fully optimized on other cases) from beginning (some manufacturers are more active in Linux compared others). To have full support (drivers) you may need some more time (a lot in case of new architecture, and more if there is no good documentation, see e.g. GPU in "Apple Silicon"). And you need more time (if every it will get it) to have full support in programs and games (and libraries).